How to show texture in defined bounding box on a sphere as if geocoordinates
I have this icosphere as earth with ocean currents

I also have extremely high resolution ocean currents in this area here

The global ocean currents are just WGS84 flat image that I use generated coordinates on (I know i need to rotate them 90deg later)


Now I have this high resolution section

How can I apply some sort of transform so that it is properly shown on the icosphere given the bounding box of the square? [min_lon,min_lat,max_lon,max_lat]
I think I could do this if I could somehow use UV --> Generated or something. And just scale the UVs of the texture to the bounding box. But I don't know how to do this directly via generated.
I do not want to use a UV sphere because that makes the poles look weird. Icosphere from Generated coordinates looks the best.

I know this is not the exact answer you're looking for, but have you thought of adding a UV sphere "already" with lots of subdivisions from the beginning?(Instead of using a subdivider)
The image below compares:

UV 32 x 16 original divisions + subdivider (bad)
UV 128 x 64 original divisions (good)
Ico (forgot the original divisions) + subdivider (good)



Now, mapping can still be quite a pain, so I made a sheet for that.
Where first column is X (long), second is Y (lat). The formulas are written in columns D and E.


And the mapping


After doing more testing I think my question using generated coordinates is impossible. So this is great! How did you figure out the lat/lon coordinates?

By testing, sliding and figuring out where the image goes. Positions for scale = 1 start from -1 to 0. Scale affects position

@TheJeran, of course you should use your exact values, I took mine from google.
